# Looking for title of children's fantasy novel where the spirit of Britain is aroused from narcotic slumber by the words "non dignus est"

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

I would have read this in the late 60s or early 70s. I remember that Britain is suffering from social breakdown. Our heroine finds the 'spirit of Britain' (possibly King Arthur?) in a cave, dosing his pain with morphine. Dragging up some school Latin, she changes the situation by telling him "Non dignus est" (*"It is not worthy*").

This was a long time back, but that narrative climax still sticks with me and I'd like to know what book it was, and maybe re-read it.

Comment: Hopefully this will be enough to find your story. :)

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/289572.The_Changes? Probably a bit late for you.

Comment: "*Non dignus est*" actually means "It is *not* worthy."

Comment: @Valorum The publication date of 1991 given on your Goodreads link is for that particular edition of the _Changes_ trilogy in a single volume. _The Weathermonger_ was first published in 1968, and so the time frame works perfectly.

Comment: Thank you @Valorum for the accurate suggestion and helpful editing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Valorum's comment is correct; it's *The Weathermonger* by [Peter Dickinson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Dickinson), the first published but last by internal chronology of the *Changes* trilogy.

You have misremembered it in a couple of ways. It's Merlin, not Arthur, in the cave. And the Latin our heroine uses to describe his situation is "Indignum est".

> Both times Geoffrey knew that Merlin had fought away the delirium
>   which had engulfed him for the last five years. Sally’s voice became
>   pleading. She wasn’t whispering now, but almost shouting. “Indignum
>   est,” she said several times, “indignum nominis tui.”

Comment: Funny how memory distorts things - I'm not surprised it was Merlin rather than Arthur, but I was pretty confident about the words. Thanks for the great match up - I've just ordered a copy!